# Meaning of "You are pretty chipper for a guy who found out they died for nothing"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

This is a dialogue extract from the movie *Captain America: Winter Soldier*. Can you help me explain what it means?

> You are pretty chipper for a guy who found out they died for nothing.

Please explain its meaning and how it's used. Is it a phrase or something else?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! What do you want us to do with your quote?

Comment: Do also be aware that this is a site for professional linguists and grammarians, you might want to see our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) for help learning and understanding English.

Comment: And also keep in mind that spoken English is often much more informal than written English.

Answer (score 3):

> You are pretty chipper for a guy who found out they died for nothing

**Pretty chipper** means that they are happy, in this case surprisingly happy as they've discovered that they died for no reason.

Overall it could be synonymous to the following passage:

> You are quite happy for a person who discovered that they died for no reason